# "... which influenced me ..." or "... which was what influenced me"

Tags: phrase-choice

Q: How did you learn to play the guitar?

- A1: My mom was a guitarist, which influenced me.
- A2: My mom was a guitarist, which was what influenced me.

What's the difference? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: What do you think the difference is, and why?

Comment: @JRodge01 A2 was the one I saw somewhere, and A1 is something I made based on my grammar knowledge. Being a non-native, I couldn't come up with something like A2 in my wildest dream. For all I know, the nonrestrictive relative clause is something that provides added infomations and needs you to write with a comma in front of it. I have no idea why they would go through the trouble of adding "was what" part as in A1.

Comment: You will hear native English speakers using both constructions. However your examples are a bit awkward as you are saying that were influenced by your mother's being something (a guitarist) rather than by her directly. A neater response (although not to your question) might be **I was influenced by my mother, who was a guitarist**.